# WPF Treeview adding sub items from database

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a function that is supposed to return a list of repositories including their subs called LoadAllRepositories.

This is the typical output from it:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "ACC",
    "TenantId": "11ff3c48-2b82-41a2-b4f2-ca914e2701c0",
    "ApplicationId": "793b0f48-5fea-4e89-8650-602a43099342",
    "Path": "DIRONE/ACC",
    "LinkPath": null,
    "Applications": null,
    "CreatedOn": "2020-09-25T16:25:59.196927"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "parent": "1",
    "text": "2020",
    "TenantId": "11ff3c48-2b82-41a2-b4f2-ca914e2701c0",
    "ApplicationId": "793b0f48-5fea-4e89-8650-602a43099342",
    "Path": "DIRONE/ACC/2020",
    "LinkPath": null,
    "Applications": null,
    "CreatedOn": "2020-09-25T16:26:17.893116"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "BCC",
    "TenantId": "11ff3c48-2b82-41a2-b4f2-ca914e2701c0",
    "ApplicationId": "793b0f48-5fea-4e89-8650-602a43099342",
    "Path": "DIRONE/BCC",
    "LinkPath": null,
    "Applications": null,
    "CreatedOn": "2020-09-25T16:25:59.196927"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "parent": "3",
    "text": "2020",
    "TenantId": "11ff3c48-2b82-41a2-b4f2-ca914e2701c0",
    "ApplicationId": "793b0f48-5fea-4e89-8650-602a43099342",
    "Path": "DIRONE/BCC/2020",
    "LinkPath": null,
    "Applications": null,
    "CreatedOn": "2020-09-25T16:25:59.196927"
}
```

if the parent is #, that means it is a root item.

I am trying to dynamically populate my treeview in wpf using this data schema but so far I have been unable to properly do it. My current code returns a stack overflow error due to it looping to infinity. I am just stuck on how to solve this issue and how to display it on the view.

Here is the function:

```
private List<DocumentRepository> LoadAllRepositories(string ApplicationId, string TenantId)
{
    List<DocumentRepository> data = new List<DocumentRepository>();
    List<DocumentRepository> initialData = new List<DocumentRepository>();
    var gtl = GetAllRepositories(ApplicationId, TenantId);
    if (gtl == null)
    {
        Error("Unable to establish a connection to the Server");
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        return null;
    }
    foreach (var item in gtl)
    {
        initialData.Add(new DocumentRepository
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            parent = item.parent,
            TenantId = item.TenantId,
            ApplicationId = item.ApplicationId,
            text = item.text,
            Path = item.Path,
            LinkPath = item.LinkPath
        });
    };
    var c = GetChildren(gtl, null, TenantId);
    return data;
}

private List<DocumentRepository> GetChildren(List<DocumentRepository> Input, string ParentId, string TenantId)
{
    if (ParentId == null)
    {
        ParentId = "#";
    }
    List<DocumentRepository> data = new List<DocumentRepository>();
    foreach (DocumentRepository child in Input.Where(x => x.parent == ParentId && x.TenantId == TenantId))
    {
        child.Children = LoadAllRepositories(ApplicationId, TenantId);
        data.Add(child);
    }
    return data;
}
```

My View:

```
<TreeView Name="DocumentRepositoryTreeview">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding lar}" DataType="{x:Type model:DocumentRepository}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var lar = LoadAllRepositories(ApplicationId, TenantId);
    var dis = new ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>(lar);
    this.DataContext = dis;
    DocumentRepositoryTreeview.ItemsSource = lar;
}
```

Comment: Core or Framework?

Comment: It seems like your algorithm to replicate the tree structure from the JSON source needs some optimization. To get maximum efficiency it is important to know if the input is already ordered according to a certain tree traversal algorithm. Generally if  this information is not available, you must first parse the JSON to C# models and add them to a flat collection of nodes e.g., `AllNodes`.

Comment: Find a root node (current node) and add all nodes that reference this node as parent to the current node's child collection by iterating over the `AllNodes` collection (if each node has only one parent, you can remove it from the `AllNode` collection). Repeat this for every child (recursively - breadth-first ). After reaching the leaf level, find the next root node and start over again.

Comment: I think the overflow is happening because you always start from the beginnig on every iteration of `GetChildren`. Since this method calls `LoadAllRepositories` for each child, `LoadAllRepositories` wil cal `GetAllRepositories` over and over again --> you never leave the first level entering an infinite loop. When you try to implement my previously described algorithm you should be fine.

Comment: @aepot Framework.

Comment: @BionicCode thanks for answering, may I know if you have an example I can follow? Currently I already convert the JSON result to a c# model. Do you mean that I should run 2 loops, first to discover the root nodes, then another loop to populate the children?

Comment: Every tree has branches. Your tree seems to consist of multiple root nodes. The goal is to build the tree structure branch by branch. So after you have all nodes created from the JSON objects, you pick the first root node (step 1). Then build this branch using recursion (step 2). Return to step 1 until all root nodes (branches) are handled.

Comment: Where `parent` is pointing to? `TenantId`? Thus your example is invalid because item with id 2 have no existing parent. As resutl i can't test the answer with this data. Can you fix the json? Possibly you can show a larger but valid json example.

Comment: @aepot if parent is # then it is the root, parent points to the Id. TenantId is just another field that has other uses there.

Comment: @aepot My apologies, I have edited the json to be more accurate. The parent field points to another Id.

Comment: The binding in your posted code won't work: `lar` is a local variable. You can only bind to a public property. If the source object is a `DependencyObject` you should implement this property as `DependencyProperty`. Otherwise the source should implement `INOtifyPropertyChanged`. See [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0).

Comment: When you set `ItemsSource` directly you are overwriting/removing the binding set in XAML. The recommended approach is to use data binding like shown in my example.

Comment: Because you have set the `TreeView.ItemTemplate` directly the `TreeView` knows only how to display the root item. You must specify a template for each level. Since all items are of the same type, it's sufficient to move the template to a `ResourceDictionary` e.g. `Windowe.Resources` and define the template implicit by defining only the `HierachicalDataTemplate.DataType` without a `x:Key`. [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the example. I stored the json into the file "data.json"

**INPC Implementation**

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Data**

```cs
public class DocumentRepository : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository> _children;

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string LinkPath { get; set; }
    public string Applications { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository> Children
    {
        get => _children;
        set
        {
            _children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (File.Exists("data.json"))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
            List<DocumentRepository> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DocumentRepository>>(json);
            LoadTree(items);
        }
    }

    private void LoadTree(List<DocumentRepository> items)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>(items.Where(x => x.Parent == "#"));
        if (Items?.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DocumentRepository childNode in Items)
                LoadChildren(childNode, items);
        }
    }

    private void LoadChildren(DocumentRepository node, List<DocumentRepository> items)
    {
        node.Children = new ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>(items.Where(x => x.Parent == node.Id));
        if (node.Children?.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DocumentRepository childNode in node.Children)
                LoadChildren(childNode, items);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DocumentRepository}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Attach View Model

```
private MainViewModel VM;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VM = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = VM;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VM.Start();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just a basic example how you could build the tree from a JSON response. You may have to adjust criteria to map child to parent (it's a depth-first traversal opposed to my originally suggested breadth-first).

Note that if you know if and how the JSON response is ordered you can safe significant time by eliminating the searching of the root node and it's related nodes.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TreeData",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>)));

  public ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository> Tasks
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>) GetValue(MainWindow.TreeDataProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.TreeDataProperty, value);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
    this.TreeData = new ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>();
  }

  public void ConvertJsonToTree(string jsonResponse)
  {
    List<DocumentRepository> allNodes = GetAllNodesFromJson(jsonResponse);
    IEnumerable<DocumentRepository> resultTree = BuildTree(allNodes);
    this.TreeData = new ObservableCollection<DocumentRepository>(resultTree);
  }

  private IEnumerable<DocumentRepository> BuildTree(List<DocumentRepository> allNodes)
  {
    var tree = new List<DocumentRepository>();

    while (allNodes.Any())
    {
      var rootNode = allNodes.First(node => node.Parent == null);
      allNodes.Remove(rootNode);

      CollectChildren(rootNode, allNodes);
      tree.Add(rootNode);
    }
    return tree;
  }

  private void CollectChildren(DocumentRepository parentNode, List<DocumentRepository> allNodes)
  {
    foreach (DocumentRepository childNode in allNodes.Where(node => node.Parent == parentNode.ParentId))
    {
      parentNode.Children.Add(childNode);
      allNodes.Remove(childNode);
      CollectChildren(childNode, allNodes);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindeo.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DocumentRepository}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeData}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing an example. I get an error at allNodes.Any saying that it cannot convert method group Any to non-delegate type bool.

Comment: Please add `()`to it. It's a method: `Any()`. I have updated the example.

Comment: When it gets to parentNode.Children.Add(childNode), I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object error. It seems like I need to instantiate the Children field in my DocumentRepository class?

Comment: You should initialize the `DocumentRepository.Children` collection from the constructor of `DocumentRepository ` (always do this. Never leave uninitialized members after the constructor returns).

Comment: I see, then how would I display this in a treeview?

Comment: You can create a `ObservableCollection` from the result (if you intend to update this tree dynamically `new ObservableCollection(resultTree);` and then bind this collection to `TeeView.ItemsSource`. Otherwise you can bind the `resultTree` (or the value returned by the example's `ConvertJsonToTree()` directly to `TreeView.ItemsSource`.

Comment: Do you know how to setup a `TreeView` using [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netcore-3.1#examples)?

Comment: Where is your code located? Are you using a view model or the code-behind of your `MainWindow`? Then I can show you a short example how to display  the tree.

Comment: I'm using the code behind my Mainwindow. At this moment im trying to bind it to the view.

Comment: I added my view to the question. Currently it only shows the root item.

Comment: I see, I'm trying to implement your solution now. How will it work with Window_Loaded?

Comment: You should call `ConvertJsonToTree` from the `Window_Loaded` handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this! Unfortunately I just couldn't understand the part about the dependency property.

Comment: You should read [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0). A dependency property is a special property that will update the binding target e.g. `TreeView.ItemsSOurce`, if its value changes. Since this example assigns a new `ObservableColection` to the `TreeData` property, this `TreeData` property has to be a `DependencyProperty` so that the data binding can update the `TreeView`. Same principle like `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but better performance.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer uses a slower algorithm to build the tree. But the difference should not be relevant, if you don't have too many items (or JSON objects). If your tree is expected to be bigger you should consider to improve the algorithm.